# Spring 3.1: Handling session timeout

Tags: spring-security, spring-3

I have an application that is wired with Spring 3.1 authentication. I have some pages which makes AJAX requests to show some information on the dialog. Now, if the user's session has timed out, the Spring redirects to the login page. I don't want an AJAX based login page. I would like the user to be navigated to the login page entirely, by canceling current operation. Once user logs in, navigate user back to the last page where he was (from where the AJAX request was made).

The redirection stuff works fine if the request is made from a page.

Answer (score 1):

The class which performs the redirect to the login page is the `LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint`. I would write a customized `AuthenticationEntryPoint` implementation which detects the Ajax request (for example, by looking at the `Accept` header), and sends an error code instead of performing a redirect.

You'll still have to detect this on the client side though. There's not much Spring Security can do there, but you should be able to reload the current page from Javascript, which will force a login, followed by a redirect to the original page (default Spring Security behaviour).

Comment: could you give me an sample code how to redirect from ajax call?