# How to make log out page redirect when we have ajax call

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have spring web application and I have user authentication using Spring security. Everything goes fine, it works well.

This is my config file.

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/home**" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/forbidden" />

    <form-login  login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/admin" authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="NAME" password-parameter="PASSWORD" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true"  logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login?logout" />
</http>

<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
       <password-encoder  hash="bcrypt"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="query"
            authorities-by-username-query="query" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Ok. Everything seems well. But I have one problem. when session is ended (caused by timeout) if user interact with page and there was Ajax call, I can't redirect to login page. In the other words I have problem only at Ajax calls.

[image]

The response of this call is login form page. but I do not need content of page  I need to redirect there.

[image]

is there any solution with Spring Configuration? If there is something please give me sample of code.

I might [found one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569417/spring-3-1-handling-session-timeout) but there is no sample of code. I'm not sure if this is the one that I need.

Comment: There isn't (at least not easy solution). The redirect is handled transparently by the browser (as per the spec), the only solution would be to detect on the server that it is an ajax request (by adding a header or something like that) and when an ajax request is detected don't redirect but send a different status code (248 or something) with a location header and process that on the client.

Comment: could you tell me how to detect if this if this is ajax request and how to add the header info? could you give me an sample code and I vote you. thanks.